# Dump memory of process which exits immediately

Tags: linux, dump, haskell, reverse-engineer

I am doing a little keygen challenge (written in Haskell), which accepts one commandline argument (a license) and exists after checking if the provided string is valid or not.

Hence I am not able to dump the memory (in order to see if the binary has some decoded license values stored), because I cannot use `gcore -o output <pid>` since the application does not wait.

Is there a way to dump the memory some how of a binary, which does exit immediately?
I also tried to attach it to gdb and then dump the memory of gdb, but I don't know if this is giving me the correct memory, and also there is much other noise from gdb in the dump.

Also do you have some other hints on how I should proceed in doing this challenge? Already tried `ltrace`, put without much information.

Comment: `gdb` is the correct way to dump the memory, but due to the way Haskell works, you won't be very happy with a memory dump. Depending on what kind of binary you got, you could try using Haskell debugging tools, but even that might not be easy. The main challenge here is to translate the Haskell machine configuration into something readable.

Comment: Also, the reverse engineering stackexchange, or some Haskell-related site (reddit `r/haskell` ?) may be a better place to ask

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check them out. My idea was that maybe the binary decodes the flag itself (I hope so atleast)